# Same git repository, multiple apps on different Heroku accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have this scenario:

I need to provide the same application to different clients, but they would have access to their own database and their own heroku account.

For example if I have 20 clients, when I make a push to my github repo, all their apps who are connected to my repo should be deployed(and run a rake task like db:migrate)...so I can easily update the application.

The clients shouldn't have access to the application source, just to their own database and command line.

Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved with heroku? Are there any services that do that?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably looking at a multi-tenant application.  https://www.allerin.com/blog/multi-tenancy-in-rails/ https://quickleft.com/blog/what-is-a-multi-tenant-application/ https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails

Comment: Thanks for the links. It can be made as a multi-tenant application, but I don't need to get that far. Everything should be separated, like as a new application, just on deployment to use the main repo as source code, all the important data will be stored in heroku env variables for each app. The clients will have their own process, own heroku app that can be accessed from their own url...

Comment: If each user has access to a "command line", won't that give them access to the source? My solution would be to use a CI app like Codeship to run a sequence of tasks (so the `git push`, the `rake db:migrate`, etc) on each Heroku app in turn, or, if you'll always be doing it locally, just put a list of those commands into a .sh file and run that.

Comment: Thanks guys. As for hiding the code I'm thinking of using JRuby. I never used JRuby, but I assume if they don't have access to git repository, they can't access the code from the rails console